# Insert an element to a lemon graph library map without copying

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, dictionary, lemon-graph-library

I'm using [Lemon Graph Library](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) and I want to add an item to a lemon map without copying it or asigning. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lemon/list_graph.h>
#include <lemon/maps.h>

using namespace lemon;
using namespace std;

typedef lemon::ListDigraph             LGraph;
typedef lemon::ListDigraph::Arc        LArc;
typedef lemon::ListDigraph::Node       LNode;

class MyNode {
public:
    CrossRefMap<LGraph, LArc, std::string> inputs;

    MyNode(const LGraph& graph) : inputs(graph) { }
};


int main(){
    LGraph graph;
    LGraph::NodeMap<MyNode> nodes(graph);

    LNode n = graph.addNode();
    nodes[n] = MyNode(graph); // error: object of type 'MyNode' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted

    return 0;
}
```

The main problem here is the CrossRefMap which needs initialization in constructor and has has no copy consturctor or assignment operator. I could use pointer to this structure instead, but this solution doesn't satisfy me. How can I solve this problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated. ;)

Comment: How about providing a _move-constructor_, or possibly define some kind of _swap member function_ and do something like `MyNode(graph).swap(nodes[n])`

Comment: It's nice idea, but I just noticed, that when I add move constructor to Node I need to add copy constructor too ;/ Lemon uses coy constuctor in map initialization. So I still don't know how to insert lemon map to a lemon map this way.

Comment: What about using any wrapper around `MyNode`? That wrapper would be a smart pointer or `reference_wrapper`.

Comment: And what about using move assignment operator `MyNode& operator=(MyNode&&)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no possibility to do it with standard `lemon` maps, so I implemented my own one based on `std::map`. I can track changes in the graph and update my map using lemon graph observers.